# Oracle Select Count > 1

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with below fields. I would like to get the concat of Part_No, Line_Item, Exp_Date, 601_Elem Only where the count of this concatenation is greater than 1. So I should get only the first 2 rows. So far, I was able to to achieve with the below code. However, I want to display all the fields in my result including ACE_Elem but not a part of concatenation. When I do that, there are no results since ACE_Elem has unique records.

Is there a way I could achieve this?
Many Thanks!

```
SELECT Part_No, Line_Item, Exp_Date, 601_Elem
FROM AUDIT
GROUP BY Part_No, Line_Item, Exp_Date, 601_Elem
HAVING COUNT(Part_No || Line_Item || Exp_Date || 601_Elem) > 1
ORDER BY Part_No
```

```
Part_No        Line_Item         Exp_Date          601_Elem      ACE_Elem
1A1                 1           12/01/2020            A             B
1A1                 1           12/01/2020            A             C
1A2                 2           01/10/2021            B             D
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple method if you want just one column is to aggregate the values together:

```
SELECT Part_No, Line_Item, Exp_Date, 601_Elem,
       LISTAGG(ACE_Elem, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ACE_Elem) as ACE_Elems
FROM AUDIT
GROUP BY Part_No, Line_Item, Exp_Date, 601_Elem
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY Part_No;
```

Your code is basically equivalent to `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`, so you might as well use that.  (The only exception would be if all columns were `NULL`.)

However, if you want all columns, then an alternative is to use window functions:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (SELECT a.*,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Part_No, Line_Item, Exp_Date, 601_Elem) AS cnt
      FROM AUDIT a
     ) a
WHERE cnt >= 2
```

Comment: Gordon, the second method using window function worked. Many Thanks for your help!